# Azure Scale Set VMS use Docker Image

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

Testing usage of Azure Scale Set VMs integration with Azure Devops Agent Pools.  I've read the docs about creating custom VM images, but I haven't seen a way to specify an OCI image to use - is this possible?

Comment: Anything you still do not understand? Or if it solves your puzzle please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible. Actually, the Azure Scale Set is a group of load-balanced VMs. And Azure VM only can be created from the VM image or the VHD file. So currently, it does not support the OCI image for the VM, also for the Azure Scale Set.